# NGINX - Two WordPress Installations, subfolder rewrite provlem

Tags: wordpress, nginx, url-rewriting, plesk

I have two WP installations on my webspace, one in the root directory and one in a subfolder "/blog". The rewrite rules are set on, but if i want to access a url, for example:

https://www.xyz.de/blog/blogpost1/

I get a 404 Error. The rewrite rules on the root directory works perfectly.

Following my gninx configuration, probably someone can help me:

```
    if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php break;
}

gzip on;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_types text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript text/javascript application/javascript application/json;
gzip_vary on;
gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";
```

Comment: great mark! Congrats!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add additional location break, make sure it comes within server { } and not within another location case. Try this one it should work

```
location /blog {
index index.php;
try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;
}
```

OR

```
location /blog {
index index.php;
try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php last;
}
```